# Why does running aws update-service from the cli cause a vim like window to popup expecting some input?

Tags: bash, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

Running
`aws ecs update-service --cluster cluster-name --service service-name --force-new-deployment --region ap-southeast-2` opens:

```
{
    "service": {
        "serviceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-2:000000000000:service/service-name",
        "serviceName": "service-name",
        "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-2:000000000000:cluster/clustername",
        "loadBalancers": [
            {
                "targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-2:000000000000:targetgroup/targetgroupname",
                "containerName": "containername",
                "containerPort": 5000
            }
        ],
        "serviceRegistries": [],
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "desiredCount": 1,
        "runningCount": 1,
        "pendingCount": 1,
        "launchType": "FARGATE",
        "platformVersion": "LATEST",
        "taskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-2:000000000000:task-definition/service-name:43",
:
```

and blocks my shell until I press `q`. This used to work just fine. I think I updated my AWSCLI and it's caused this. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it to update my service in my CI Scripts?

Comment: I think you are using AWS cli v2 is that right? This is happening to me as well.

Comment: @marcincuber Yep version 2.0.7

Comment: I believe this is a default behaviour for that version. It would be good to know whether it can made non-interactive just like v1. If it is causing issues for you simply install latest version of v1 cli.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as described on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html:
you can add the `--no-cli-pager` option to your command to disable the pager for a single command use.

in your specific example:

```bash
aws ecs update-service --cluster cluster-name --service service-name --force-new-deployment --region ap-southeast-2 --no-cli-pager
```

it will still print the output to the command line (but not halt and block your script's further commands by opening vim like previously)

this is better than disabling the pager, or redirecting the output to `/dev/null`, since you still get to see the output if you want to. (you could also redirect the output to a file `./output` if you'd want to keep the output)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this behavior and tried a number of things to work around it before finding the [AWS Documentation, How to use the AWS_PAGER environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)

Windows:

```bsh
C:\> setx AWS_PAGER ""
```

Linux and MacOS:

```sh
export AWS_PAGER=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the default behavior of the AWS CLI 2. This should solve your problem (as I don't think there is a built in way to make it "quiet" or silent).

aws ecs update-service --service svcName --desired-count 1 > /dev/null

I wouldn't recommend going back to an older version unless as a last resort.

Comment: Specifically the `/dev/null` on the end of the command does it for me